# SuperMicro 119-7 - Install Problems 'no device driver found'

Tags: raid, windows-server-2012, installation, lsi, megaraid

I have a set of servers that had Debian installed, and need to have Windows Server 2012 R2.

- Supermicro 119-7 / 10274-WRFT+
- MegaRAID SAS 9266-8i

Mount R2 in a flash drive, boot from it in UEFI mode
Error: no device drivers found.
Mount latest drivers from LSI on IPMI 'ISO'
Browse to these, choose the appropriate drive.
After the server thinks about it for a minute it reports 'no device drivers found'.

I'm strongly considering ditching the RAID card in favor of software RAID.  If only to get on with things.  I'll admit some of this is frustration - this is Day 3 of working on this problem, opened tickets with LSI, and SuperMicro, etc.

Without visiting the machines (they are 40 miles away) how would one disable the RAID card?

Or I can work through the problem - I have a feeling it's something dumb about Windows that I don't get - perhaps I was a linux guy for too long.

There is a RAID set, and disks that are not in the RAID set.  Latest firmware (23.28.0) and signed, latest drivers (6.703.03).

Edit

This problem has been resolved.  FWIW ..

I burned 2012 R2 Standard (X19-28929) to USB, mounted that in the server, booted from it to install.

Following a vague suggestion from LSI, I looked at our download folder from MS Network, and discovered the download copy of 2012 R2 Standard was X19-03239.

I loaded this ISO as a removable mounted drive (we talk to our remote servers via IPMI), booted from *that* and it accepted that without any issues.  I offer two conjectures

- The version really does make a difference
- Something wacky is going on with the USB drive install process.

I'd like to take the opportunity to re-vist this issue with a space host when I have the chance, try the working method of install with the suspect version of R2, but realistically I may not have time.  If I do, I'll update.

Answer (score 2):

This problem of drivers not recognised (in my case it was megaraid sas 8708em2) when building 2012R2 off USB stick is really wacky. Wasted a good part of my day, looking for LSI (now Broadcom) drivers, finding them (Windows 8.1 apparently works for 2012R2) but not having any success. USB install I can confirm does not work for this particular LSi raid. So I configured the server to boot from pxe option and enabled 2012R2 build image on my WDS server.
Pressed F12 and was able to install the same OS I had on USB stick, this time no problems with missing drivers.
What is it that makes installation of 2012R2 possible using pxe method, and impossible using USB method (identical ISO media used), I do not know. I do not even have "X19-03239" ISO, the version is different but the solution is to use pxe method instead. Hope this helps, albeit 3 years down the line.